# Changing date-time variables while iterating through a command in every step?

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, variables

I have a python script. I am trying to run it from the terminal (Linux). It requires variables. The command is like this :

```sh
Python_script.py -p Foldername -s 2020-08-18T19:45:00Z -e 2020-08-18T20:00:00Z ~/Image_name.png
```

`-s` specifies a starting sub-folder named by date-time (`2020-08-18T19:45:00Z`) and `-e` specifies ending sub-folder named by date-time (`2020-08-18T20:00:00Z`). I have a folder which has many subfolders named by date-times, so I am seeking to iterate through the subfolders and for each I need to change the `-s` and `-e` variables.

How can I iterate through the command while changing the date-times variables in every step?

Comment: What determines the `-s` and `-e` variable's values for each (sub)directory? i.e. How are they determined?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. -s and -e are (sub)folder names -- named after time interval. For example, I would be storing data in one sub-folder for every fifteen minutes. And then next folder. If I choose to analyze one hour of data in one run of the command, I will be taking four folders for the run. For that , if -s is  2020-08-18T19:45:00Z, -e will be 2020-08-18T20:30:00Z . For the next run, I want -s to be  2020-08-18T20:45:00Z and -e to be 2020-08-18T21:30:00Z and so on.   Thanks.

Comment: Python has a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta) class that you could use to compute a `datatime` value for each subdirectory (from some starting point). You can also use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get a list of the items in a given folder, and you can check to see which are subdirectories by using [`os.path.isdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir). After doing all that, you should have enough information to invoke your processing script.